# List of FindBugs 2.0 bugs by rank?

Tags: java, static-analysis, findbugs

I know there is [list](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html) of bugs, but I would like to have a list with additional information about rank (1 to 20 in version 2.0) or at least about ranking groups (Of concern, Troubling, Scary, Scariest).
Maybe I'm missing something, but FindBugs forum does not seem to be active?!

Comment: findbugs has internal categories like high, medium, low. But I can't find the docs that cross reference the Bug patterns with priorities.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps http://code.google.com/p/findbugs/source/browse/trunk/findbugs/etc/bugrank.txt but I don't know if it is exhaustive ([FindBugs Bug Descriptions](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html) has more entries).

Comment: Be aware: The bugrank file uses relative ranks, like "+4". The actual rank for a bug is combined from this relative rank, its defined priority (as mentioned in the question comment above) and the rank of its category, afair, and then limited to the maximum rank of 20.

If the bug is not mentioned by name in the txt file, its category will determine its rank.

I could provide a code reference, if you want.