# Relationship of FindBugs bug rank, category and type

Tags: findbugs, spotbugs

I'm using FindBug and I want to understand the .XML report generated by it for documentation purpose.

Sample I got is below.

```
<BugInstance type="RANGE_ARRAY_INDEX" priority="2" rank="7" abbrev="RANGE" category="CORRECTNESS" first="1">
```

So as it seems type `RANGE_ARRAY_INDEX` of category `CORRECTNESS` is having rank `7` so  it is a `scary` one. So is it always true ? Is `RANGE_ARRAY_INDEX` always a `scary` one ?

***I couldn't find any resource mentioning about a relationship among them.***

I referred to [FindBugs Bug Descriptions](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html) and [FindBugs 2 site](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/findbugs2.html)  and [this SO question which dose not have a clear answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9583953/list-of-findbugs-2-0-bugs-by-rank)

As it seems we have several Categories,

1. Bad practice
2. Correctness
3. Experimental
4. Internationalization
5. Malicious code vulnerability
6. Multithreaded correctness
7. Performance
8. Security
9. Dodgy code

And

- Scariest (1-4),
- Scary (5-9),
- Troubling (10-14)
- Of Concern (rank 15-20)

And we have many types as it's in the doc.

Can anyone help me on this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15116885/1005481) by David Harkness which explains it pretty well, partly cited below. I also checked the [SpotBugs code](https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs). SpotBugs is [FindBugs' successor](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12885549). In short:

- **Type** - This is just the name of the BugPattern which was found.
- **Category** - The category is for grouping BugPatterns, hardcoded in FindBugs. For example, `RANGE_ARRAY_INDEX` will always fall in the `CORRECTNESS` category (and it's reported by the *DumbMethods* detector).
- **Rank** - Rank is the result of complex calculations, can vary, and indicates the severity of the found bug. *It varies from 20 (lowest) to 1 (highest), and the UI groups the values into four categories: `scariest`, `scary`, `troubling`, and `of concern`.* (Harkness) So, a certain NullPointerException might get a 1, and a potential performance improvement might just get a 12.
- **Priority** - Also a calculated value which varies. It indicates the confidence that the found bug is actually a bug. FindBugs employs heuristics which may go wrong. It varies from 1 (highest confidence) to 5 (lowest confidence, to be disregarded). For a long time now, priority has been renamed *confidence* in order to make this clearer. The XML still says `priority` for compatibility reasons.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. `So, a certain NullPointerException might get a 1, and a potential performance improvement might just get a 12.` Still those have `mights`. Isn't NullPointerException always gets rank 1 ? If not what is the criteria of rank calculation.

Comment: Yes, these are heuristics. There is a [BugRanker](https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs/blob/3.1.0_RC5/spotbugs/src/main/java/edu/umd/cs/findbugs/BugRanker.java#L39-L79) framework, specific [adjustments](https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs/blob/3.1.0_RC5/spotbugs/etc/bugrank.txt), and possible influence by the analyzed code. All of this influences the final rank.

Comment: Hmm then NullPointerException  might get a rank other than 1. ?

Comment: Yes, absolutely!